# Redirect from page1 to page2, two questions

Tags: asp.net, redirect, web-config

I have a **my-site.ru/page1.apsx** which will be a part of **my-site.ru/page2.aspx** so I need to rewrite (or redirect ?) page1.aspx to page2.aspx

I added this to my web.config:

```
 <system.web>
    <urlMappings enabled="true">
      <add url="~/page1.aspx" mappedUrl="~/page2.aspx"/>      
    </urlMappings>
 </system.web>
```

The only thing I don't know hot to fix is: why text in address bar is my-site.ru/page1.aspx but i see my-site.ru/page2.aspx ?? I want while redirecting (rewriting) text in address bar changes too.

Question2:  How will it reflect on SEO of page1.aspx ? If possible, please, provide a link. i'm a SEO beginner.

*PS: I'm not a native english speaker so there must be some errors*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are not going to need the content reflected on page1.aspx or if you are going to move the content to your page2.aspx, I would suggest you to do a [301 redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301), which is a a **permanent redirect** this will affect your seo passing all the SEO information to the page you´re doing the redirect which is page2.aspx in this case.

from the seo perspective other things you can do are:
- remove page1 from your [xml sitemap](http://www.practicalecommerce.com/articles/3623-SEO-Understanding-XML-Sitemaps) (if you have any)
- Exclude the page from [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html)

to perform a redirect either you can do it in IIS 7 (or above) you can include an element in your web.config like:

```
<httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent">
     <add wildcard="/page1.aspx" destination="/page2.aspx" />
</httpRedirect>
```

or you can code the redirection and check for the url in each request like:

```
public class RedirectHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
          context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(this.context_BeginRequest);
    }

    private void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
          HttpContext context = application.Context;

          //check here context.Request for using request object 
          if(context.Request.FilePath.Contains("page1.aspx"))
          {
               context.Response.RedirectPermanent("/page2.aspx");
          }
    }

}
```

if you are using .NET 4.0 or above take a look to the [permament redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.redirectpermanent.aspx)

just be aware that if you perform a regular response.redirect you are doing a 302 redirect that will affect your seo.

Comment: web.config code doesn't work. i deleted page1.aspx, added your web.config section, entered mysite.ru/page1.aspx and got 404 error ...

Comment: why are you deleting page1.aspx? I though the case is to perform a redirect from one url to another without affect the seo!

Comment: Content of page1.aspx will be a part of page2.aspx, so I don't need page1.aspx. Am I right ? I cannot redirect from non-existing pages ?

Comment: if the page doesnt exist your best bet is doing a redirect by code (httpmodule) but instead of using the filepath you'll need to change it to request.url

Comment: So I can't do this via web.config ?

Comment: not sure but if you´re getting a 404 you´re reaching the request by that given url so the redirect isn´t happening, make sure your iis is configured to support that http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpredirect

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43797/discussion-between-pedro-and--)

Comment: Oops, I completely forgot to mark your answer as useful. Sorry. About a solution: I simply deleted old file and created a new one.

Answer (score 0):

on page load
Write this 
server.transfer("Page2.aspx")

Comment: mmm, I want to delete page1.apsx. Is it possible to delete page1.aspx and make server.transfer in web.config ?

Comment: I just tried your answer and still get same result: it redirects to pages2.apsx but text in address bar is still page1 ..

Comment: ohkk,,, then on load try  response.redirect("www.<fullpath>/page2.aspx")

Comment: response.redirect will change the location in your address bar